# How to load jsonlines file with simple file read

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonlines

Consider having the following code and a `jsonl` file,
there is a specific reason I don't read file with `jsonlines.open()` api, so please take this as a fact.

Reference for jsonlines package:
https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#jsonlines.Reader

```
import jsonlines

with open('example.jsonl', 'r') as jsonl_f:
    content = jsonl_f.read()

with jsonlines.Reader(content) as reader:
    lst = [obj for obj in reader]
```

`example.jsonl` content:

```
{"hello": "world"}
{"covid": "19"}
```

Error I get on `lst=` line:

```
 lst = [obj for obj in reader]
  File "../lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonlines/jsonlines.py", line 204, in iter
    skip_empty=skip_empty)
  File "../lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonlines/jsonlines.py", line 164, in read
    six.raise_from(exc, orig_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
jsonlines.jsonlines.InvalidLineError: line contains invalid json: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1) (line 1)
```

Comment: You aren't reading the content as a UTF-8 string, so python most likely loads it into some binary format.

Answer (score 8):

```
import jsonlines

with jsonlines.open('example.jsonl', 'r') as jsonl_f:
     lst = [obj for obj in jsonl_f]
```

The **jsonl_f** is the reader and can be used directly. It contains the lines in the json file.